# How to handle leaving message on website in python

Tags: python, email, web, message

I am developing my first website. I have page where people can leave message to me. What I am doing is sending a AJAX call to the server, and the server gets the content of the message, then login in an gmail account and send the message to another gmail account using python's email libraries smtplib and email.

It works ok, but the problem is it takes more than one minute on my laptop, the loading image on the client side would keep spinning during the time. I think the bottleneck is login().

```
mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()

# login, send email, logout
mailServer.login(conf.user, conf.pw)
mailServer.sendmail(conf.user, to, msg.as_string())
mailServer.close()
```

So is there any way to speed this up, or other ways to do this.

Thanks

Comment: is sendmail installed on your server?

Comment: @dm03514 Isn't it just a method of library smtplib?

Answer (score 0):

So the delay is probably caused by Google's SMTP server as they do a reverse lookup of the IP address of your webserver - mail systems often do this as part of sending e-mail.

What you have coded is only needed if you intended to send mail out from your account - that is when you need to perform authenticated SMTP. If you want to only mail your own account then you can remove the login step. Note, that you will have to change the mail server from smtp.gmail.com to one of Google's inbound mail (MX) servers. Also, if you are performing a simple forward you will have to handle e-mail rejection or other connection problems so having your script dump the mail to a simple mail server running on the mail server would be helpful.